# WMS GetFeatureInfo Request

Tags: wms, getfeatureinfo

I am attempting to teach myself how to make a basic [GetFeatureInfo](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo) request on a WMS (specifically from [Geomet](https://ec.gc.ca/meteo-weather/default.asp?lang=En&n=C0D9B3D8-1), GetCapabilities [here](http://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet/?lang=E&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities)). The following returns 400 Bad Request, and I'm not sure if it is a simple syntax error, or something more systematic.

Request:

http://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=GDPS.ETA_GZ&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&BBOX=-20037508.342789244%2C5009377.085697313%2C-17532819.799940586%2C7514065.628545966&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&QUERY_LAYERS=GDPS.ETA_GZ&X=100&Y=100

Parameters:

```
SERVICE:WMS
VERSION:1.1.1
REQUEST:GetFeatureInfo
LAYERS:GDPS.ETA_GZ
STYLES:
SRS:EPSG:3857
BBOX:-20037508.342789244,5009377.085697313,-17532819.799940586,7514065.628545966
WIDTH:256
HEIGHT:256
QUERY_LAYERS:GDPS.ETA_GZ
X:100
Y:100
```

On the other hand, the following similar GetMap request works:

Request:

http://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet/?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=GDPS.ETA_GZ&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&HEIGHT=256&WIDTH=256&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&BBOX=-17532819.799940586,5009377.085697313,-15028131.257091932,7514065.628545966

Parameters:

```
SERVICE:WMS
REQUEST:GetMap
VERSION:1.1.1
LAYERS:GDPS.ETA_GZ
STYLES:
FORMAT:image/png
TRANSPARENT:true
HEIGHT:256
WIDTH:256
SRS:EPSG:3857
BBOX:-17532819.799940586,5009377.085697313,-15028131.257091932,7514065.628545966
```

The GetCapabilities document lists the GDPS.ETA_GZ layer's SRS as 4326, but I've attempted using lat/long coordinates, as well, to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though the INFO_FORMAT parameter was also required. The following works:

Request:

http://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=GDPS.ETA_GZ&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&BBOX=-20037508.342789244%2C5009377.085697313%2C-17532819.799940586%2C7514065.628545966&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&QUERY_LAYERS=GDPS.ETA_GZ&X=100&Y=100&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fplain

Parameters:

```
SERVICE:WMS
VERSION:1.1.1
REQUEST:GetFeatureInfo
LAYERS:GDPS.ETA_GZ
STYLES:
SRS:EPSG:3857
BBOX:-20037508.342789244,5009377.085697313,-17532819.799940586,7514065.628545966
WIDTH:256
HEIGHT:256
QUERY_LAYERS:GDPS.ETA_GZ
X:100
Y:100
INFO_FORMAT:text/plain
```